# Understanding Render Function - Is it actually called on each re-render?

Tags: vue.js

I read that the render function gets called each time there's an update, but that doesn't appear to be the case.  I created this codepen to show my findings.  Is the render function only actually called once?

```
render: function (createElement)...
```

https://codepen.io/DedicatedManager/pen/wvvYaXO

Answer (score 2):

The `render()` function is executed with each change, you can see this by placing a simple `console.log('render!')` inside.

Why doesn't the rendered structure re-create the removed element? Well that's because of the internal **Virtual DOM** representation of the actual DOM that Vue uses. The Virtual DOM **isn't aware** that one element was removed because the "remove action" didn't pass through it.

As long as Virtual DOM is concerned, that element is still there, so it doesn't touch the actual DOM in order to re-create it. This is what Virtual DOM's "diff" is about.

---

Note that this concept isn't exclusive to Vue, React for example [states this in its docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html#integrating-with-dom-manipulation-plugins):

> React is unaware of changes made to the DOM outside of React. It
>   determines updates based on its own internal representation, and if
>   the same DOM nodes are manipulated by another library, React gets
>   confused and has no way to recover.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I forked the codepen to add a remove button created by Vue and get the same results.  What am I missing?   https://codepen.io/DedicatedManager/pen/GRRYWLv

Comment: You are still removing the div via DOM, even if that function is inside the render function. Remember that you have to go the "Virtual DOM" way, which would mean for example introducing a conditional in the render function in order to not render that div.

Comment: You can even inspect the Virtual DOM at runtime, because it's just an object, Check my forked codepen: https://codepen.io/yuriy636/pen/yLLRrWQ You can see that pressing the "remove inside of Vue" button doesn't even trigger a re-render, because nothing has changed for Vue (because you used the DOM directly). But if you input some text in order to trigger the re-render you can see the logged Virtual DOM, where in the `children` property there is a still a reference to the `div` element.